# Access the first element of a list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I am using python, i want to use loops to access the first element in each list in a list of lists and compare it with other elements.
My list is like this.

```
word_app = ['jack', [1, 2], 'big', [1], 'large', [2]]
```

I want only to compare the first elements.

```
Jack with big.
Jack with large.
...
```

Comment: @Sujay i get only "jack"

Comment: ```for i in word_app:``` then ```if isinstance(i,list):``` then ```print(i[0])``` then ```else: print(i)```

Comment: You said you want to compare the first elements of the nested lists, then your example output compares the strings which are *not* nested lists. Which one do you want?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo i want to compare the strings

Comment: then ```for i in word_app```, ```if isinstance(i,str): print(i)```. This will give you all the strings in the list

Comment: @Sujay it worked

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
word_app = ['jack', [1, 2], 'big', [1], 'large', [2]]
```

Create a new list using list comprehensions, adding just the strings values

```
string_list = [x for x in word_app if isinstance(x, str)]
```

And then validation

```
for i in range(1, len(string_list)):
    print("Is {} equal to {}".format(string_list[0], string_list[i]))
    print(string_list[0] == string_list[i])
```